# How to sort and display a collection from firestore database using ionic angularfire 7.4.1

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I been stuck in developing my first ionic angular project that has a chat feature. I can't find a complete tutorial regarding angularfire 7.4.1. I like to sort the chats in the message display by its timestamp, but the tutorial I found was 2 years ago and it can't seem to work.
I use the code from the most resent tutorials I found, but it only displays the collections randomly.

[image: service]

[image: page typescript]

[image: page html]

I expect to display the messages from the collection, sorted based at its timestamp.

Comment: Rather than using screenshots of your code, could you kindly copy and paste your code using codeblocks? It makes your code more accessible (screen readers will be able to read it) and allows for foilks to copy and paste the snippets to try it out themselves.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Theres an example directly in the readme in github repo. https://github.com/angular/angularfire.

```
const collection = collection(firestore, 'items');
this.item$ = collectionData(collection);
```

as for the sorting part, you use the js sort method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort